# Adding the text in a text box to a database table using OData and Knockout Js

Tags: javascript, sql, html, knockout.js, odata

I am trying to add a value in some drop downs and text boxes to a table in sql database. Its works fine with the drop downs but with textboxes it adds NULL values to the table columns even though I have entered the values in the textboxes

**HTML**

```
<td>

                <select data-bind="options: $root.locationNames, optionsText: 'LocationName', optionsValue: 'LocationName', value: selectedLocation, optionsCaption: 'Location'">
                </select>
            </td>

            <td>

                <select data-bind="options: $root.pipelineNames, optionsText: 'PipelineName', optionsValue: 'PipelineName', value: selectedPipeline, optionsCaption: 'Pipeline'">
                </select>
            </td>


            <td>

                <select data-bind="options: $root.counterpartyNames, optionsText: 'CounterPartyName', optionsValue: 'CounterPartyName', value: selectedBidCounterParty, optionsCaption: 'Bid CP'">
                </select>
            </td>

<td>
                <input type="text" name="bidVolume" data-bind="value: $root.BidVolume"/>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="text" name="bid" data-bind="value: $root.Bid"/>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="text" name="offer" data-bind="value: $root.Offer"/>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="text" name="offerVolume" data-bind="value: $root.OfferVolume"/>
            </td>
<td >
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: add, enable: selectedChoice" value="Add New Entry" />
            </td>
```

**Knockout Js with OData**

```
self.selectedChoice = ko.observable();
    self.selectedTerm = ko.observable();
    self.selectedLocation = ko.observable();
    self.selectedPipeline = ko.observable();
    self.selectedIndex = ko.observable();
    self.selectedBidCounterParty = ko.observable();
    self.selectedOfferCounterParty = ko.observable();

    self.bidVolume = ko.observable();
    self.bid = ko.observable();
    self.offer = ko.observable();
    self.offerVolume = ko.observable();



    self.add = function (canadiancrude) {
        var payload = {
            Term: this.selectedTerm(), Product: this.selectedChoice(), Location: this.selectedLocation(), Pipeline: this.selectedPipeline(),
            BidCP: this.selectedBidCounterParty(), BidVolume: this.bidVolume(), Index: this.selectedIndex(), Bid: this.bid(), Offer: this.offer(),
            OfferVolume: this.offerVolume(), OfferCP: this.selectedOfferCounterParty()//, Locked: "0", Sequence: "", TermID: "0"
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/odata/Canadiancrudes',
            type: 'POST',
            //  data: ko.toJSON(payload),
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
```

May I know where I am making a mistake in that?

Comment: doesn't look like your binding to the values in bid, offer, & offerVolume, no?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, edited the question, please check

Comment: have you debugged your receiving method that calls the sql query to ensure you've received values you are expecting? maybe it's your insert/update method?

Comment: Yes It is calling sql query and that is the reason it works fine with the drop down lists in the same table as in the above code.

Comment: I understand your sql query is calling appropriately...my question was pertaining to the data coming into your query from the service call. Are the data items in question also null in the request?

Comment: I used break point to check whether my query is receiving the values and I noticed that it is taking null for the text boxes bid, bidVolume, offer and offerVolume but in the case of drop down lists, the query is taking the right values. Probably some issue passing the values in the textbox to the query. not sure why

Comment: for your data, try just using ko.toJSON(self) and remove your 'payload' { first modify your object's property names to match your JSON model }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small mistake in binding data corrected and is as follows

```
        <td>
            <input type="text"  data-bind="value: bid"/>
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="text"  data-bind="value: offer"/>
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: offerVolume"/>
        </td>
```